# JPanel inside another JPanel: Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, boxlayout

I am writing a program that should display information on a radio station and I want the user to get that information by clicking on an image of a channel that they like.

The channels are set upp with a grid layout but what I want inside of each grid is both the image of the channel and the name of the channel right under the image. So I thought a `BoxLayout` inside of a `GridLayout` would do the trick but I am not getting the GUI to look like I want.

```
 jf = new JFrame();

      jf.setTitle("tutorial");
      jf.setSize(500, 500);
      jf.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
      jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      JButton jButton1 = new JButton("first");
      JButton jButton2 = new JButton("second");
      jPanel.add(jButton1);
      jPanel.add(jButton2);
      jf.add(jPanel);

      grid = new JPanel();
      grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4,5,10));
      grid.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);


      JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
      jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      JButton jButton = new JButton("first");
      JButton jButton12 = new JButton("second");
      jPanel.add(jButton);
      jPanel.add(jButton12);
      grid.add(jPanel);
      grid.add(jPanel2);

      jf.add(grid);
```

Here is some sample code of my attempt to put a box layout with two buttons into a grid layout.

How should I go about putting one layout inside another?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) *"I am not getting the GUI to look like I want."* How does it look? A screenshot would be handy. If you don't have enough rep. to embed the screenshot as an [edit], upload it to an image sharing site and provide the link.

Comment: `what I want inside of each grid is both the image of the channel and the name of the channel right under the image` - you can add an image and text to the same button. Read the API there are methods that allow you to set the location of the text relative to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> [...] what I want inside of each grid is both the image of the channel and the name of the channel right under the image.

see [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html):

> [image]
>
> ```
> ImageIcon middleButtonIcon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
>
> ...
>
> b2 = new JButton("Middle button", middleButtonIcon);
> b2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
> b2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
> ```